# Accessing token outside of controller in NodeJS/ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

My token is available in `req.headers.authorization`. I want to save this as a global variable so that in another file, say a `model`, I can also access it without explicitly passing it to my model.

Is this possible?

Comment: i guess pass the token into your persistency code, so you can manually make a second database call for audit alongside the main one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since node/express applications remain in memory as a running process (assuming you are using it as a server), I would be concerned that assigning a request value to a global might cause some serious security issues if you are storing authorization info.

```
var globalAuth;

(function() {
  [].slice.apply(arguments).forEach(function(reqAuth) {
    globalAuth = reqAuth;
    // Simulate async operation
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(reqAuth, globalAuth);
    }, reqAuth);
  });
})(100, 10, 50);

// outputs
//   10 50
//   50 50
//   100 50
```

Comment: Then what do I do? I need to access the logged-in user id in a model as part of an audit script that should happen automatically. I don't want to manually pass the variable over. What if I use `app.set('user', user)`?

Comment: This is what [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) is for. Have you tried that approach yet? [`app.set`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.set) is essentially setting an application global so you would end up with the same issue as stated above.

Comment: Yeah I understand the middleware use, but that would explicitly require me to include it. What I have is an audit table and I have set triggers on my models so that upon changes (such as `insert`, `update` or `delete`), a copy of it is saved in the audit table (this serves a different purpose that SQL auditing). These changes to tables can occur at any point on any routes, and using middleware would then require me to do so manually.